Shutdown and reboot buttons are greyed out in XFCE on Alpine Linux
I installed Alpine Linux with XFCE on an old potato laptop, without any display manager. I've been able to iron out most of the hiccups by searching through various wikis and forums. However I'm unable to make the power buttons work (the ones used to shutdown and reboot). They are greyed out!
Many people have had the same issue in the past, but none of their accepted answers work for me:

Alpine's wiki mentions that elogind and polkit-elogind should be installed and the computer should be rebooted, but that doesn't solve the issue.

A few posts on Arch's forum from 10~15 years ago mention that the user should be in the power group, but it doesn't seem to exist on Alpine. (My user is in audio, disk, floppy, netdev, plugdev, users, video, and wheel.)

Other posts talk about writing exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch startxfce4 or exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session startxfce4 instead of exec startxfce4 at the end of .xinitrc (one example here), but none of the suggestions change anything to the problem (I also tried mixes and variations of the different suggestions). I previously only had the line exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session startxfce4 in my .xinitrc.

I also tried to add config files for polkit as described here. The path /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d seems to have been replaced with /etc/polkit-1/rules.d in Alpine, but it still doesn't fix the problem. I also tried with the lines Identity=unix-group:power replaced with Identity=unix-group:plugdev, since the power group doesn't exist in Alpine, but nothing different.


How to fix this?

Maybe I'm late...but I just configured a complete instance.
In my case I just set this rule in the /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/ folder (50-reboot-shutdown.rules but name it as you like):
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
  if (action.id.indexOf("org.freedesktop.consolekit.system") == 0
    &&  subject.isInGroup("wheel")) {
    return polkit.Result.YES;
  }
});

Be sure that you user is in the group wheel, if not add it or just change the rule putting a group that is meaningful.
That worked for me.
Take note: don't waste time putting rules with polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN; no root password login popup will show up.
